# Could linear bearings bear axial load?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings

With linear bearings, could they be used to join one rod with another to form a cross-junction and rotate with around a 0.3N-mm torque? Suppose the rods are fairly thin, eg, 5mm in diameter. That is, could linear bearings bear a radial load? Would the bearings deform?

**UPDATE** Here's a diagram

[image]

Suppose the blue rod is attached to a gear driven by a motor. The blue rod itself is also attached to the bearing's housing. The blue essentially rotates and drives the black, exerting force/stress on the bearing. The idea is to mount a slidable camera on the black which can be rotated by the green gear.

Comment: The point of linear bearings is that they do not resist axial loads, they slide axially and only resist radial loads.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what configuration you're describing, can you sketch it for us?

Comment: @ethan48 sorry, by axially I actually meant radially. That is, whether turning a linear bearing radially would deform or damage the bearing.

Comment: @Air Sure. I've added a diagram to my OP.

Comment: OK, got it. The blue rod will be able to spin along with the red bearing while the black rod stays stationary. The blue rod will also be able to move back and forth along the length of the black rod. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Ethan48 I've updated my OP with a better diagram and description now. Essentially, I'd like to rotate the black rod by driving the blue rod (or green gear) whilst the black rod can still slide. I wonder if linear bearings could typically take that much radial stress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bearing should have figures on the moment loads it can take. Failing that, use two bearings and allow them enough movement so effectively each is just supporting a purely radial load.